# Racket/Scheme C++ Extensions and Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, scheme, racket

So I have been writing some racket extensions for some C++ classes using the tutorial (http://docs.racket-lang.org/inside/overview.html)  on the racket site and have been able to successfully load them into racket. However I was wondering if I can use inheritance to reuse some code.

For example I have two classes that I have written in C++, Foo and Bar.

Class Foo looks like this:

```
Foo { 
    func1() { /* ... do stuff */ } 
}
```

Class Bar looks like this:

```
Bar : Foo {
     func2() { /*... do more stuff /*} 
}
```

I've currently written a single .cpp racket extension that creates Bar and creates the extensions for both func1() and func2(); however, I'd like to create two racket extension classes. One extension that does only functions inside Foo and then I just want to include Foo_ext.h (my racket extension to Foo) in Bar_ext.h so I have access to all the functions.

So I currently have this:

Bar_ext.cpp:

```
func1_racket_ext() { /*... do racket stuff and run func1() */} 


func2_racket_ext() {/* ... do more racket stuff and run func2() /*} 


/* Scheme initializes etc... */
```

But what I really want is:

Foo_ext.h:

```
func1_racket_ext() { /*... do racket stuff and run func1() */} 



/* Scheme initializes etc... */
```

Bar_ext.cpp:

```
#include "Foo_ext.h" 


func2_racket_ext() {/* ... do more racket stuff and run func2() /*} 



/* Scheme initializes etc... */
```

Is this even possible? I feel like namespace might be an issue. This would be extremely useful for me because it would allow me to not write lots and lots of redundant code since I have many classes that use class Foo as a super class.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated and if you could point me to an example (maybe there is something in the underlying racket code you can point me to?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution to this is more straight forward than I had originally thought. The fallacy is that I wanted to include on extension in another, this is not necessary. The key is to create the extensions separately implementing each function you want to expose to racket and each function references a pointer to the object. For example:

Foo_ext.cpp (pseudo code)

```
static Foo * foo; 
Scheme_Object * create_foo(...) {
    foo = new Foo(); 
    return make_scheme_ptr(foo); 
} 

Scheme_Object * do_func1(..., Foo * f) 
{
     foo = f; 
     /* do func_1 stuff */ 
 } 

 /* ... Do scheme stuff... */
```

Then the same code would be done for bar_ext.

The key here that in the racket script where you want to use your extensions you require both extensions:

```
(require "Foo_ext.rkt") 
(require "Bar_ext.rkt")

; my_bar is the pointer to the bar created. 
(define my_bar (create_bar))

; Pass 11 and the my_bar pointer to func1 declared in Foo_ext  
(func1 11 my_bar)
; Pass 12 and the my_bar pointer to func2 declared in Bar_ext
(func2 12 my_bar)
```

And that's all she wrote...